# Access all audio files of device in ionic 2

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

Im trying to make a music app where the app reads all the audio files avaliable on the device (also sorts them according to albums and artists). Just like inbuild music player avaliable on any android phones.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the exact solution but a workover

```
 this.file.listDir('file:///storage/emulated/0/', 'Download')
.then((data) => {

    for (var counter = 0; counter < data.length; counter++) {
        if (!data[counter].isDirectory) {
            var directoryName = data[counter].name;

            var re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;

            var ext = re.exec(data[counter].name)[1];
            if (ext == 'mp3') {
             //gives the list of all .mp3 audio files
            }
        }
    }
});
```

install the file plugin form [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/), follow the steps how to use plugin.
The above code ONLY gets .m3p files in "Download" folder on your android mobile(if the Download folder is there).